# How to capture pdf form fields with QR code?

Tags: android, pdf, itext, qr-code

I would like to utilize QR codes to capture PDF form data on an android tablet.

The user will be given a dynamic pdf form on a tablet, and once they answer the form questions I would like to generate a QR code. This QR code will be scanned by an admin in person and used to capture the form data (in an offline environment)

Can iText do this, or is there another library I should look into?

Any pointers on how to implement this would be appreciated. Thanks